# Google Tasks Migration to Exchange account

Tags: gmail, migration, task, exchange-server

I have retrieved Tasks from my Gmail account using OAuth 2.0 Dot Net Google client library (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/tasks/v1). When I save any of these tasks to my exchange account using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices Dot Net library, the date of Task is adjusted automatically, although the time zone of Gmail account and exchange account are same i.e.  Central Time (US & Canada). I want to prevent this automatically adjustment in Task date.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using Calendar time zone. Basically, Google Calendar has time zone information. I retrieved time zone information from primary calendar and then before saving Task to Exchange account, I converted due date to UTC with following C# code

```
if (task.Due.Value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
                        {
                            dueDateUTC = task.Due.Value.ToUniversalTime();
                            unspecifiedKindDate = new DateTime(dueDateUTC.Year, dueDateUTC.Month, dueDateUTC.Day);
                            dueDateUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(unspecifiedKindDate, Utility.OlsonTimeZoneToTimeZoneInfo(timezone), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
                        }
```

This code first of all find out that whether Task due date is in local time zone or not. If it is in local time zone then due date is converted into UTC. After converting into UTC, a unspecified kind datetime object is created through following code

```
unspecifiedKindDate = new DateTime(dueDateUTC.Year, dueDateUTC.Month, dueDateUTC.Day);
```

This unspecified kind datetime is then again converted to UTC with the help of following code

```
dueDateUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(unspecifiedKindDate, Utility.OlsonTimeZoneToTimeZoneInfo(timezone), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

Now this "dueDateUTC" object is used to save Task information into Exchange account. On saving Task, Exchange server automatically converts dueDateUTC to mailbox time zone and this was desired. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the time zone on the ExchangeService object to the user's time zone. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn789029(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Jason, I am writing a generic application for any exchange mailbox in any time zone. So I don't know the time zone in prior.

Comment: It is still a consideration. You have to look at the values from the Google export. Are they in UTC, or in some time zone? The Managed API defaults to the local time zone of the computer where it is running, and all time values you set get translated as if they are in that time zone.